# different application bar in panorama windows phone for navigation

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone, panorama-control, application-bar

I am start developing application for Windows Phone 8.
As usual, there is something coming up. yups, that is error. LoL
I have an application using panorama, and I planning to put an appbar for each panorama item which will generate different appbar for different panorama item.

Luckily, I've found a tutorial about it. Here is the link :
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394036(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394036%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

My problem is, how can I navigate to other windows phone page (known as xaml) from this App.cs??
Because when I start implement what I've known it bring me an error.
Any help and answer will be appreciated. ^_^
Thank you so much.

Regards,
Budi Prasetyo

Comment: Sorry, I've just got it. :)
Here is the solution from my case above.
[_LINK_](http://windows-mobile-dev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-application-bar-in-windows.html)

And now, I got another problem T_T
How can I pass a parameter from my mainpage.xaml or mainpage.cs, to app.cs?
In my case, one of my appbar is for delete an item from listbox which I already made it as observablecollection<T>.
I just want, passing and ID, and check it in appbar event handler is the ID null or not null, so I can do my code behind.

Thanks before. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "How can I pass a parameter from my mainpage.xaml or mainpage.cs, to app.cs? "

You can create a public property in your App.cs, something like:

```
  public int ItemId {get; set;}
```

As the App context is available everywhere, you can access it via your MainPage.cs.

```
  App.ItemId = your ID here
```